# In-App Purchase, SKProductsRequest returning 0 - Products still in Review

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have followed the tutorial: [Introduction-to-in-app-purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introd) 
I think I have everything done exactly how it is shown. But, my in-app purchases are still "Waiting for Review" in iTunes connect.  When testing my app, I don't get errors, I just get 0 products returned to me.

- I have submitted the app then rejected the binary.

Do my products have to be approved first? I am using a development profile, is this incorrect? It has been more than 24 hours and I can't figure out why they won't show.

My app is not ready and I just want to be testing them to make sure everything works.

Comment: Have you uploaded a new binary and self-rejected it? Seems to be a required step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to delete my app from the device and install it again.  Then I see the products like I should!

Comment: @Nitin , of course, nope. Inapp purchases are not supported by simulator.