# Reasons for SKProductsRequest returning 0 products?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to set up IAP but after making a call to retrieve the products using SKProductsRequest the SKProductsResponse array within my delegate has a count of 0. Here's my checklist:

- Test product has been added to iTunes connect
- The product's bundle id matches the app bundle id (and its not using a wildcard)
- The product identifier set in the SKProductRequest matches the product created on iTunes connect
- I've waited several hours since the product was created on iTunes connect
- The provisioning profiles enable IAP
- Followed all steps in various tutorial such as http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ etc.
- Have deleted app from device, relaunched Xcode, rebuilt etc. etc.

Any other suggestions as to why the fetched product count is zero?

I don't believe this will be a coding issue, but here it is anyway:

```
…

NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"redacted", nil];
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
[self.productsRequest start];

…
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    NSLog(@"Product count: %d", [products count]);
    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product: %@ %@ %f", product.productIdentifier, product.localizedTitle, product.price.floatValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare your code with the following code, that worked for me: https://github.com/wolf81/NewsHack/blob/master/FSProductStore.m

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe it can be a code issues as there are only several lines so far. Adding them above anyway

Comment: I think you could just copy my class, change some identifiers and try to use it for purchase? Perhaps your issue is the environment you test with.

Comment: The code I have posted is effectively already identical to the relevant portions of your code. What environmental factors need to be taken into consideration?

Comment: Whether you connect to the production or test environment is one of the things you might have to keep in mind.

Comment: How do you change from connecting to the test or the production environment? I have set up an iTunes Connect test user account, however as the product count fetch is 0 its not possible to proceed further and thus log-in to the device as as the test user. I read on another SOV question that if you sign the app using the development profile it uses the sandbox and if you use the distribution profile it uses the production environment? Is this correct? I've tried both however.

Comment: In the example I posted I use a different URL, depending on whether the app is build in Debug or Release configuration. This is achieved using preprocessor macros. Check the `Constants+Headers.h` file in the project.

Comment: Also: yes, I believe the environment is related to the provisioning profile used.

Comment: I am also facing this issue.@Chromium Dioxide is  this issue solved then can you give me solution.

Answer (score 46):

Check all 3 things in the list below
1) check your product identifiers - they must be exactly the same that you have in your code and in iTunes Connect -> My Apps -> YourAppName -> Features -> In-App Purchases
[image]
2) iTunes Connect -> Agreements, Tax, and Banking -> Master Agreements -> Paid Applications-> Contact Info / Bank Info / Tax Info (should be filled)[image]
3) code to test it

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var requestProd = SKProductsRequest()
    var products = [SKProduct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        validateProductIdentifiers()
    }
}

extension ViewController: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    func validateProductIdentifiers() {
        let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(["candy100", "someOtherProductId"]))

        // Keep a strong reference to the request.
        self.requestProd = productsRequest;
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }

    // SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol method
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        self.products = response.products

        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print(invalidIdentifier)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed today, indeed the "Paid applications" contract has to be in effect for the IAP to be returned by SKProductRequest. If the contract is pending then [0] will be returned.

Comment: so it won't work even in test mode if bank and tax info is not filled?

Comment: worked for me after completing the tax form and adding all the contacts. Before it did return 0 as well.

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you have In-App Purchase turned on in the Capabilities section.  If you don't, SKProductsRequest will return 0 products.

Comment: That simple solution solved the problem for me! In the sandbox I had everything working, there was no indication that there was anything anything wrong, even with an optimized release build. But the app store version had crashed on every purchase attempt.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue...

> I simply change **my bundle identifier** which does not match with an
>   **iTunes bundle identifier**.

And my app runs well :)

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same problem, Solved it by sending just the IAP Product name rather than my bundle id before the product name. Here is the example :

**works**
`SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"my_product"]];`

rather than

**doesn't work**
`SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.my_site.my_app.my_product"]];`

Comment: did the job, by the way i was using helper classes from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

In the off chance that you've overlooked this, the product identifier match is case sensitive.

So, if you've created a product on Apple with an identifier of say

> com.yourcompany.product1

and you call the product request with a product identifier of

> com.yourcompany.Product1

Your list will be returned with zero products.

This kept me busy for a while :-)

ps: On a separate project, I found SKProductsRequest only started returning products after a restart. So, if all else fails, try restarting your Mac.

Comment: +1 Can't believe it. None of the solutions here worked for me, but the restarting of Mac. That worked!!! Maybe restarting the Xcode project would have been enough though. Didn't test that.

Answer (score 5):

IN swift 5, I am facing the same problem getting Skproducts count 0. I solved this
Goto [image]iTunes Connect -> Agreements and Tax if status is New there then there should be term view button besides status click it fill the complete form and then the paid apps will be shown status active and Skproducts counts would be visible in xcode console.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a troubleshooting checklist for the case when SKProductsRequest returns zero products (source https://fluffy.es/zero-iap-products-checklist):

> 1. You must have a paid Apple developer account
> 2. Your free and paid apps agreements status are active
> 3. You have added the necessary Tax information
> 4. You have added Banking information
> 5. You have created an explicit App ID for your app
> 6. You have created an app in App Store Connect, with the correct App ID
> 7. You have created the in-app purchase item in App Store Connect
> 8. Your in-app purchase product status is 'Ready to Submit'
> 9. Your app is using the correct signing Team / provisioning profile
> 10. Your app's bundle ID in Xcode is the same as App Store Connect
> 11. You have added In-App Purchase capability to your app's Xcode project
> 12. You are using the correct product ID when calling SKProductsRequest
> 13. You have waited at least 15 minutes after creating In-App Purchase item Subscription to access all app content and content updates.

Answer (score 2):

Some times there are very carrying solutions to these types of problems. After doing some research, I found that it sometimes helps to delete the app and then install it again([In-App Purchase, SKProductsRequest returning 0 - Products still in Review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903078/in-app-purchase-skproductsrequest-returning-0-products-still-in-review)) Also what version of iOS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, however I've tried that a few times. Its for iOS7. My product status is "Waiting for Screenshot" - this is the state it is supposed to be according to Apple's TN2259 technical note regarding testing IAP.

Answer (score 2):

Also, keep in mind that agreeing to the Paid Applications cotract is not enough. You also have to fill out the contact, bank and tax information for that agreemant specifically, for it to be considered done.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go to iOS's **Settings > iTunes & App Stores** and **Log out**

Hope this help you, I don't know why :D

Answer (score 1):

Please also whether you have set price of the product in iTunesConnect or not.I missed that and products were zero.Wasted my whole day to figure out this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting an empty `SKProductsResponse.products` array on *some* macOS 10.14 systems while others work just fine and return the valid list of current IAPs for my app.

**Same** app, identical code.
User logged into **the same App Store account** on both machines.

That's just plain weird.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 xcode 12.4 **simulator** returned zero products.

**Using a physical device returned products properly**

Comment: Where is that quote from? Please include the proper attribution as per [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 0):

After digging a lot, following steps solved my issue of getting 0 products for SKProductsRequest.

Go to **Settings > Sign in to your iPhone** on your iOS device. If you're already logged in with your original Apple ID, tap on it and choose **Sign Out**. Then simply sign in with the credentials for the sandbox tester you created in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was a bug. In simulator all product identifiers fails and was marked as invalid. In real device all product request successfully fetched a product.

TvOS 4K

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue even after accepting the Tax and Agreements Section in App Store. I use to change my Apps bundle Id many times(for sending builds to testers), I suspected this could be the issue. So I fixed this issue as follows.
 Go to `Target -> BuildSettings -> Search for "Product Bundle Identifier"`. It should be `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.
 After updating this go to `General -> Bundle Identifier`. Enter your proper bundle Id which has In-App purchase capability. After doing this changes I'm able to list the products