# Is it possible to test in-app-purchase without having to enter bank details etc?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to test IAP, however it seems this isn't going to be possible without going through multiple hoops on iTunes Connect and entering bank information etc.

[Reasons for SKProductsRequest returning 0 products?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394359/reasons-for-skproductsrequest-returning-0-products/21414734?noredirect=1#comment32305297_21414734)

Can anybody confirm if this is the case or not? If so then is there any reason why I can't just create a dummy test app entry in iTunes connect, enter garbage for the bank info, then after finishing testing delete the app entry from iTunes connect?

Comment: Just use your personal bank for the moment. It's not like Apple have your secret PIN. All they can do is deposit money.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes you can test IAP without entering bank info. what you need to do is

1. Create a test user in itunesconnect
2. Run your app on an actual device
3. Launch AppStore App on your iphone/ipad
4. logout and login with your test user id
5. Go to your app and try to make an in-app purchase
6. You should get a prompt saying something like "Charge $0.99 to Sandbox"
7. You won't be charged to your actual account.

This is all documented by Apple [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html)

Expand tab that says ***To perform testing for In-App Purchase products***

Comment: No, you definitely cannot test in-app purchases until you have set up your banking info. I was getting "invalid product id", but it magically started working after my banking and tax info was set up. That link you posted doesn't mention about banking or tax info.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you definitely do have to enter banking and US tax info before you can do in-app purchases. I was getting "invalid product ID", but it started working as soon as my banking/tax info was set up. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did not work for me. If it works out for you, let me know.

I tested in-app payment this late December 2013 / early January.

Comment: So you *had* to enter the bank information before you could move forward developing IAP?

Comment: In order to test with the device. Otherwise, I'd get 0 products in the response from iTunes connect.