# Swift 3 SKProductsRequest turns 0 element

Tags: in-app-purchase, swift3

I have done every step which apple says. But still cannot get products. This part looks ok. I can see 'IAP is enabled. loading' message.

```
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        print("IAP is enabled. loading")
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.companyname.appname.onecredit", "com.companyname.appname.threecredits")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }
```

And this is the SKProductsRequest of the code. Which I cannot get any product.

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product as SKProduct)
    }
}
```

The only thing, on the Agreements, Tax, and Banking section, status is still 'pending tax'. Is this the reason?

Comment: Once i had the same reason..i told my client to fill in all the info in the agreement sections..Once he setup his bank account info and other things..it worked...

Comment: After it worked, do you remember what was the status? still 'pending tax'? If not, how long did it take after your client setup?

Comment: may be 1 day i guess,it was a long time ago..

Comment: Ok mate. Thanks for your time. I did it on the weekend. Maybe better give Apple a day to see it.

Comment: however there are several resons why the products are not returned..Make sure those all are correct.See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394359/reasons-for-skproductsrequest-returning-0-products)

Comment: Do you have any check list of tutorial for me? I searched and checked maybe with 5 different answers in this website. But still cannot be sure about it.

Comment: Yes, please check [here](https://www.google.com.np/?gws_rd=cr&ei=-y8XWIPEPIfmvgTSrbAo).

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was US Tax Form. Once its approved, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I can confirm that ALL of the "**Agreements, Tax, and Banking**" in iTunes Connect need to be "COMPLETED" in full.  After I filled out all the info, it took about 30 minutes for the PROCESSING status to be finished.  Then I was able to get a response from the **SKProductsRequestDelegate** for my list of products! Yay!